# How to pass the dictionary data to TableView at cellForRowAtIndexPath with dynamic Keys and Values in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

```
    if ([[[testMenuGroupAry objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:group] isEqualToString:[filteredAry objectAtIndex:objCount]])
    {
        NSLog(@"object count is %d",objCount);
        [groupAry addObject:[itemList objectAtIndex:group]];
    }
}
    [refArray addObject:groupAry];
    [groupAry release];
    [tempDict setObject:[refArray objectAtIndex:objCount] forKey:[filteredAry objectAtIndex:objCount]];
```

am getting all the data in to tempDict, now i want to pass the tempDict to tableview?

Comment: could you please provide more details? You are trying to pass `tempDict` within same viewcontroller?

Comment: You don't want to "pass" the dictionary. You want to return a cell, an instance of UITableViewCell or a subclass. The cell has subviews which represent attributes of your model objects, or, in your case, the keys in the dictionary. But your code must create the cell (or re-use one) and configure it.

Comment: @Deepesh All the functionality has been doing in the same view controller.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What do you want to show in your table? Do you want multiple section with each key in the dictionary providing the data for one section?

Comment: So, pass it.  But you'd better have a good idea what to do with it once you get there -- no one wants to write your code for you.

Comment: @BoredAstronaut tempDict Contains Keys and Values i.e., for 1 key multiple Values is there.. how to pass these data in to indexPath.row

Comment: @rdelmar you are right! Here, Key Maintains a Section, for each section i want to show the values in the table view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it something like this. This is a pretty generic way to populate a sectioned table with a dictionary:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sortedKeys = [self.tempDict.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.tempDict count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.tempDict[self.sortedKeys[section]] count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.sortedKeys[section];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.tempDict[self.sortedKeys[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```